# Do I need to install Java 8 SDK to use Bazel Build to build C++ project?

Tags: bazel

This question comes in two part:

1. From what I can see in https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/tree/master/src/main , Bazel is written in a mix of C++, Java and some Linux .sh files. I am not sure the core is actually Java or C++. The Windows binary in release page is .exe rather than .jar, does it mean I don't need Java SDK if I never need to use Bazel to build Java?
2. If the first part is false, is it has to be Java 8 *SDK*, or Java 8 *JRE* will suffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you do need a JDK, at least JDK 8. Most of Bazel is written in Java.

On all platforms Bazel is a self-extracting binary, on Windows it's a self-extracting .exe file. The message you see upon running Bazel the first time ("Extracting Bazel installation...") also hints at this.

EDIT: I think a JRE is not enough, even if you don't build any Java rules, but I haven't confirmed this.

Answer (score 0):

[You do need a JDK](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/install.html) and it better be Java 8. I used this with Java 7 some time ago, but by now it's been deprecated.

You need the JDK, because Bazel is just a build management tool. It *invokes* other tools in order to compile and build Java projects. It does the same for C/C++ projects or Python projects etc.

Comment: "It invokes other tools in order to compile and build" That I know, but why should Bazel invoke Java SDK when I build C++ binary?

Comment: Oh, I get it. You should be fine with just the .exe then, plus the extra setup they need. The project itself is Java-first, with some helper stuff in C++ - looking at the codebase the bulk of code is in the Java parts. So if you were building it, you'd need the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here seem outdated. According to bazel's [linux installation documentation](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/4.1.0/install-ubuntu.html#step-3-install-a-jdk-optional), jdk is not needed, and a jre is bundled with bazel:

> Step 3: Install a JDK (optional) Bazel includes a private, bundled JRE
> as its runtime and doesn’t require you to install any specific version
> of Java.
>
> However, if you want to build Java code using Bazel, you have to
> install a JDK.